# Entity framework migration of Collections

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a model that looks like this

```
public abstract class Item
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime PurchaseDate { get; set; }
    public ICollection<String> Pictures { get; set; }
    public Int32 MinimumPrice { get; set; }
    public DateTime Deadline { get; set; }
    public Boolean VisibleBids { get; set; }
    public Boolean Handled { get; set; }
    public DateTime PlacementDate { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller I do

```
db.Items.ToList()
```

This leaves the Pictures field for all fetched objects null because its how the entity framework works. What is a good solution to fetch them in one query?

Comment: This is not how EF works. Navigation properties can be lazy loaded but you'd have to mark them as virtual.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you already done with Navigation properties between your tables, Now you just need to make your collection virtual and use the concept of eager loading when you need data from both the tables

```
public virtual ICollection<String> Pictures { get; set; }
```

and use include in linq like

```
db.Items.Include("Pictures").ToList()
```

So here by making virtual navigation you are saying that only take the data of related entity when you needed and whenever you need the data use the Include for eager loading.

For setting navigation properties please have a look on the code.

Suppose the scenario where we have a Post and on this we have multiple comments like

```
 class Posts
{
   public int PostsId { get; set; }
   public string PostsDescription { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<Comments> Comments { get; set; } 
}

class Comments
{
   public int CommentsId { get; set; }
   public string CommentsDescription { get; set; }
   public int PostsId { get; set; }

   public virtual Posts Posts { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: -1 Please, correct this answer. Eager loading (include) has nothing to do with lazy loading, they're alternatives. Please, learn what this is all about an correct this answer. Don't mislead other people: **make your collection virtual for lazy loading ... and use include in linq like**!!

Comment: -1 removed, but you can do it better... It's still incorrect. You only need virtual navigation properties if you want to use lazy loading. For eager loading, you don't need it. And, if a property supports lazy loading (i.e. lazy loading is enabled and the property is virtual), you can access it, ant it will hit the DB to recover the related entity or collection, provided the context has not been disposed. Please read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx. Use this info in your answer.

Comment: Could you elaborate this on the scenario I gave? Where I have no acces to the implementation of String. How do I set navigation properties there? All examples seem to use a scenario with 2 "custom" datatypes.